# first page blank latex

Tags: latex

I am using latex; however the first page is completely blank. How can I fix the issue?

Below is my latex code at the beginning of the document that I am using it and I tried to remove many parts but it seems that it is not getting fixed.

```
'\usepackage{xcolor}
 \usepackage{chngcntr}                  
 \counterwithin*{equation}{section}
 \counterwithin*{equation}{subsection}
 \documentclass [12pt]{article}
 \addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.75in}

\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.75in}
\usepackage{cite}
 %  \usepackage[natbibapa] 

%\usepackage[english]{babel}
 \usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
 \usepackage{natbib}
 \linespread{2}
 \usepackage{paralist}
 \usepackage{titlesec}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
 \usepackage{pdfpages}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage{booktabs}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{paralist}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{amsthm}
 \usepackage{latexsym}
 \usepackage{subfig}
 \usepackage{esint}
 \usepackage{authblk}
 \usepackage{comment}
 \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{lineno}
 \usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
 \usepackage{titlesec}
 \usepackage{pdfpages}
 \usepackage{eso-pic}
 \usepackage{everyshi}
 \usepackage{enumitem}
 \usepackage{array}
 \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>          
 {\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
 \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>          
 {\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
 \newcolumntype{R}[1]{> 
 {\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
 \newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
 %\usepackage(apacite}
 %\usepackage{ltxtable} 
%\usepackage{makeidx} 
 %\usepackage(apacite}
 %\usepackage{ltxtable} 
%\usepackage{makeidx}  
 \begin{document}
 \section{Introduction}
This document talks about optimizing and programming and related concepts.
minimizing tardiness of each machine.

\clearpage

 \bibliographystyle{apacite}
 \bibliography{bibfile}

\end{document}
```

I tried to solve the issue but it seems complicated to solve. I searched the forum but could not find how to handle the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @rkta I added a little more to make it more clear.

Comment: perhaps you meant \newpage instead of \clearpage

Comment: @bluesmonk Actually The page before this document talks about... is blank!

Comment: try removing elements one by one from the preamble until it works. There are many packages there that I don't know. Also, remove commented code to avoid unnecesary info.

Comment: @bluesmonk, thanks will test it.

Comment: @rkta I moved it and it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the issue by commenting the following:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
 \usepackage{chngcntr}                  
 \counterwithin*{equation}{section}
 \counterwithin*{equation}{subsection}
```